# Custom start-up page for chrome incognito mode

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, chromium, private-browsing

I know how to set a custom start-up page in chrome, for regular browsing (Settings -> On startup), but when I run in incognito mode, the home page is always the same: a gray screen with a white logo, "You’ve gone incognito" and a description of what incognito is.

I would like to change that page to my bank website so that I don't have to waste time typing the URL every time.

I tried searching for that page on my system, by recursively grepping files into `/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/` and in `/usr/share/chromium/`, but did not find it. (EDIT: I used grep also in `.config/google-chrome/` and other directories related to the browser, but without success.)

Watching its source code, I see it references a stylesheets in `chrome://resources/`, so I guess that page could be a resource as well, but I cannot locate them.

So, how can I change the startup page when I open a new incognito window?

Comment: I take it then that right-clicking the bookmark for the page and selecting *open in incognito tab* isn't good enough.

Comment: Exactly, I want to change the default behavior for every user on the system. They should see my custom page unless an URL to load is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled into a fix for this while trying to find how to set startup position.

1. make your changes in **normal mode**. If you try to make them in **incognito**; they **will fail**.
2. copy your startup page's URL to the clipboard.
3. open your shortcut to chrome OR chromium & paste the URL on to the command line after the actual command. I also add the incognito after the URL, like this:

   ```
   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U file:///home/name/file.html --incognito
   ```

Comment: If an incognito window is opened any other way than executing the shortcut, you will get the normal grey incognito start page. Add to this that your short cut now opens an incognito window by default, and this is far from perfect.